# composer install or update error, what is wrong

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.3, symfony-cache

I have a problem.
After command

```
composer update
```

I get error message

```
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\LogicException]
  An option named "connection" already exists.


Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:





    [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\LogicException]
    An option named "connection" already exists.
```

what am I doing wrong?

```
Exception trace:
 () at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition.php:232
 Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition->addOption() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:384
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->addOption() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Command\Proxy\RunSqlDoctrineCommand.php:24
 Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\RunSqlDoctrineCommand->configure() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:61
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->__construct() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\RunSqlCommand.php:36
 Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\RunSqlCommand->__construct() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:11355
 appDevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_QuerySqlCommandService() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:329
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:140
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:100
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->all() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:64
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:122
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\wamp64\www\ecommerce\bin\console:27
```

I get all project with git, and on one computer all running, on second not running.

Comment: your composer.json has a `post-update-cmd` that executes `app/console cache:clear --no-warmup`. Of which appears to be complaining that one of the Symfony Command configurations has conflicting `connection` options, potentially due to a stale cache. You may need to manually delete your `app/cache/<env>` directory before running `composer update`.

Answer (score 4):

Run the command with the `-vvv` flag. It will show you which command is broken. For example:

```
bin/console -vvv
```

I have the same error after upgrade `doctrine/dbal` package. In my case `RunSqlDoctrineCommand` (from `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` package) conflicted with parent `RunSqlCommand` (from `doctrine/dbal` package).
I've updated `doctrine/doctrine-bundle:1.12.*`, it contains fix for this case. This solved such problem.

Answer (score 4):

On PHP 7.1, I had to:

1. Update `symfony/symfony` from `3.3.*` to `3.4.*`
2. Update `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` from `^1.6` to `^1.12`

Answer (score 3):

Haven't dived too deep, but looks like `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` should have one of this versions:
2.4.3  2.4.2 2.4.1 2.4.0 2.3.2 2.3.1 2.3.0 2.2.4 2.2.3 2.2.2 2.2.1 2.2.0 2.1.2 2.1.1 2.1.0 2.0.10 2.0.9 **1.12.13 1.12.12 1.12.11 1.12.10 1.12.9**

So, update it to one of them.

For example, for 1.12 you can specify it like this at `composer.json`:

```
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.12.9",
```

And then `composer update` or `composer update doctrine/doctrine-bundle`

More details:

- https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/1170
- https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/commit/86d2469d6be06d55ad7b9e2f076f6942476f2e87

Answer (score 2):

In my case, a certain project with symfony `v3.3` failed doing `composer install` under `PHP 7.4` and also `PHP 7.2` saying `An option named "connection" already exists.`.

Tested solutions:

- Downgrading to `PHP 7.0`, it worked perfectly with SF `v3.3`
- Upgrading symfony to `v3.4`, it worked perfectly with `PHP 7.2` and `7.4`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
composer update doctrine/doctrine-bundle
```

Thanks
[IStranger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3793592/istranger)