# Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\LogicException during php bin/console server:run

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I cannot run symfony local server by command: php bin/console server:run.
I get error:
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\LogicException]
An option named "connection" already exists.

Dependencies in composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.0, <7.4",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
        "liip/functional-test-bundle": "^1.8",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.3",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
```

parameters.yml:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: tests
    database_user: root
    database_password: password
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

I think these parameters in parameters.yml used to work earlier.
I use mysql and also sqlite for tests.

Comment: What about your parameters.yml? Can we see that? You may have listed your database connection twice. Or named two connections the same thing.

Comment: I added the parameters.yml content. As you can see I have nothing to hide ;).

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue in a Symfony v4.2 project, without changing anything in my code base.

As already found in this issue https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/4565
it appears in certain versions of the `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` package (in my case v1.11). The `RunSqlDoctrineCommand.php` from vendor adds the second option which causes the error.

If you can update your `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` package, you might be fine. In my case, an update or fix by package was not possible.

### What can we do in that case?

**What comes next is more a hack, than a real good solution, so use it at your own risk!**

As statet in the commit from official repository: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/commit/86d2469d6be06d55ad7b9e2f076f6942476f2e87 (thanks to the guys in issue above)
I made a copy of the new `RunSqlDoctrineCommand.php` from that commit and save it in my project as `dist/RunSqlDoctrineCommand.php`.

In `composer.json` change the `scripts` sections as follows:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "doctrine-bugfix": [
            "cp -f dist/RunSqlDoctrineCommand.php vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Command/Proxy/RunSqlDoctrineCommand.php"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts",
            "@doctrine-bugfix"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts",
            "@doctrine-bugfix"
        ]
    }
}
```

This will just copy and override the original file in vendor directory on every `composer install/update`. This will only work on a unix/linux system, btw.

As said: Not the best solution, but it keeps your project in shape.

Answer (score 0):

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68575495/4691713) is there is a good explanation

in my case

```
composer update doctrine/doctrine-bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside (symfony project) vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Command/Proxy/RunSqlDoctrineCommand.php change configure function like below:

```
protected function configure()
{
    parent::configure();

    $this
        ->setName('doctrine:query:sql')
        //->addOption('connection', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The 
        connection to use for this command')
        ->setHelp(<<<EOT
        The <info>%command.name%</info> command executes the given SQL query and
        outputs the results:

        <info>php %command.full_name% "SELECT * FROM users"</info>
        EOT
    );
    if ($this->getDefinition()->hasOption('connection')) {
        return;
    }

    $this->addOption('connection', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The 
    connection to use for this command');
}
```